# Should I use RouteParameter or UrlParameter for an Asp.NET web-api route?

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen both being used and so I wonder, do they do the same thing or different things? If it's the latter, what's the difference?

I tried answering it myself by having a look at the visual studio MVC 4 (rc) web api template, but sadly it uses both, so my confusion remains. Here's what the template contains:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `RouteParameter` for Web Api routes (`.MapHttpRoute`) and `UrlParameter` for standard MVC controller routes (`.MapRoute`). As you know standard MVC and Web API are 2 completely distinct APIs in terms of assemblies and namespaces even if both are pretty similar. You could for example self host your Web API in a console application, so you won't even have a reference to the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly and you would of course use `RouteParameter` in this case.

Comment: Aha.. I didn't even notice that they had called different methods on the routes object. But it makes sense. I wonder why they've included views and mvc stuff in the web api template. Hope they get done with the SPA template soon. Thanks! :)

Comment: There's also different behaviour between two of these. If you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043266/in-asp-net-webapi-does-routeparameter-optional-mean-optional-part-of-the-url UrlParameter.Optional won't require you to specify default parameters, while RouteParameter.Optional will.