# In ASP.Net WebAPI does RouteParameter.Optional mean optional part of the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following routing rule:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name:          "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults:      new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints:   new { id = @"\d+"}
            );
```

And a ProductController with these actions:

```
public Product Get(int id)
{
    return _svc.GetProduct(id);
}

public int Post(Product p)
{
   return 0;            
}
```

I can call the `Get` action as expected : **GET "api/product/2"**

I thought I'd be able to call my `Post` action like this: **POST "api/product"**
but it doesn't work. I get a 404 error. It will work if I do this though: **POST "api/product/2"**

I thought by making the default value of id `RouteParameter.Optional` that it meant that the {id} portion of the url did not need to be present to match the routing rule. But that doesn;t seem to be happening. Is the only way to make another rule that doesn't have the {id} part to the URL?

I'm slightly confused. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it works as intended because you're adding a constraint to the id parameter. See this blog post http://james.boelen.ca/programming/webapi-routes-optional-parameters-constraints/ for the same scenario.

**Update:** Looks as if the original link is dead, but the way back machine has us covered:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160228013349/http://james.boelen.ca/programming/webapi-routes-optional-parameters-constraints/

Comment: The url you've given gives a 403. Please consider updating your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make the `id` a nullable int **with a default of null**

```
// doesn't work
public Product Get(int? id)
{
    return _svc.GetProduct(id);
}

// works
public Product Get(int? id = null)
{
    return _svc.GetProduct(id);
}
```

I'm about 95% sure both of these work under MVC (when declaring Optional for the route parameter), but Web API is stricter.

Comment: Ya - I was surprised too :-)

Comment: After a bit of thinking I came to that it makes sense.. Let say you have `Get(int id, int? sometihng)` so you cannot call `Get(1)` with just one parameter so this is why you have to specify default value.